# Can Django forms be used in a custom view?

Tags: python, django, view, orm

I'm using a CreateView to create an object then a custom written view to assign and update the values.
The problem is I can't get to assign multiple values to a many to many relation.

A configuration page looks like this right now:

[image]

I'm not using forms, everything is inside the template. And I have the problem with the last input, the 'Cut material' checkboxes. Since I don't use a form, it's very tricky to handle that some inputs has only one value and some of them might have multiple values (like 'Cut material').

Right now my view will request the POST data and will try to match each option with it's value, but when it get's to 'Cut material' it will get an error if I select more options. I tried some workaround to insert some hidden inputs to pass into the context more info but I had no success.

I guess if I can use forms then I might solve this issue and it will also help with validation.

**How do you think I can manage to pass correctly the value from 'Cut material' to the view to save it correctly? Also if you would do it with forms, can you guide me a little bit through  the process?
Thank you very much!**

## views.py

```
def tool_option_value_configure_view(request, tool_id):
    tool = Tool.objects.get(id=tool_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_dict = dict(request.POST)
        print(post_dict)
        option_ids = post_dict.get('option_id')
        option_values = post_dict.get('option_value')

        tool.option_values.clear()
        for i in range(len(option_ids)):
            option_id = option_ids[i]
            option_value = option_values[i]

            tool_value, created = ToolOptionValue.objects.get_or_create(tool_option_id=option_id, value=option_value)
            tool.option_values.add(tool_value)
        tool.save()
    return render(request, 'configure_tool_option_values.html', {'tool': tool})
```

## configure_tool_option_values.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %} Option Values - {{ tool.name }} {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3 class="text-center">Configure - {{ tool.name }}</h3>
                </div>
                <form method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                        {# Iterate through all options of a tool_type of a tool#}
                        {% for option in tool.tool_type.options.all %}
                            {# Iterate through all option values of an existing tool #}
                            {% for option_value in tool.option_values.all %}
                                {# When the option from the tool type matches the option from the tool's option value, #}
                                {# show an input to the user with values already completed #}
                                {# (the tool was already saved in the db before)  #}
                                {% if option_value.tool_option.id == option.id %}
                                    <p>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="option_id" value="{{ option.id }}">
                                        <label for="">{{ option }}:</label>
                                        {% if not option.extensible %}
                                            {% if not option.multiple_options %}
                                                <select name="option_value" id="">
                                                    {% for tool_option_value in option.tool_option_values %}
                                                        <option value="{{ tool_option_value.value }}"
                                                                {% if tool_option_value.value == option_value.value %}selected{% endif %}>{{ tool_option_value.value }}</option>
                                                    {% endfor %}
                                                </select>
                                            {% else %}
                                                {% for tool_option_value in option.tool_option_values %}
                                                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                                        <input name="option_value" class="form-check-input"
                                                               type="checkbox"
                                                               id="css-id-{{ tool_option_value.id }}"
                                                               value="{{ tool_option_value.value }}"
                                                               {% if tool_option_value.value == option_value.value %}checked{% endif %}>
                                                        <label class="form-check-label"
                                                               for="css-id-{{ tool_option_value.id }}">{{ tool_option_value.value }}</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            {% endif %}
                                        {% else %}
                                            <label>
                                                <input type="text" name="option_value" value="{{ option_value.value }}">
                                            </label>
                                        {% endif %}
                                    </p>
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endfor %}
                        {# If the tool was not configured before, show inputs based on the tool type options to the #}
                        {# user to configure the tool #}
                        {% if not tool.option_values.all %}
                            {% for option in tool.tool_type.options.all %}
                                <p>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="option_id" value="{{ option.id }}">
                                    <label for="">{{ option }}:</label>
                                    {% if not option.extensible %}
                                        {% if not option.multiple_options %}
                                            <select name="option_value" id="">
                                                {% for tool_option_value in option.tool_option_values %}
                                                    <option value="{{ tool_option_value.value }}">{{ tool_option_value.value }}</option>
                                                {% endfor %}
                                            </select>
                                        {% else %}
                                            {% for tool_option_value in option.tool_option_values %}
                                                <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                                    <input name="option_value" class="form-check-input"
                                                           type="checkbox"
                                                           id="css-id-{{ tool_option_value.id }}"
                                                           value="{{ tool_option_value.value }}"
                                                           {% if forloop.first %}checked{% endif %}>
                                                    <label class="form-check-label"
                                                           for="css-id-{{ tool_option_value.id }}">{{ tool_option_value.value }}</label>
                                                </div>
                                            {% endfor %}
                                        {% endif %}
                                    {% else %}
                                        <label>
                                            <input type="text" name="option_value" value="">
                                        </label>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </p>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer text-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Save</button>
                        <a href="{% url 'update-tool' tool.id %}" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Back</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

## models.py

```
import datetime

from django.db import models


class StorageZone(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'


class ToolOption(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)  # Diametru, material, ...
    extensible = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    multiple_options = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'

    def tool_option_values(self):
        return ToolOptionValue.objects.filter(tool_option=self)


class ToolOptionValue(models.Model):
    tool_option = models.ForeignKey(ToolOption, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)  # 16mm, 18mm, 20mm, carbura, HSS, ...

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.tool_option} {self.value}'


class ToolType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    options = models.ManyToManyField(ToolOption)

    # stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    # minim_stock = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} {[f"{t}, " for t in self.options.all()][:-2]}'


class Tool(models.Model):
    tool_type = models.ForeignKey(ToolType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    option_values = models.ManyToManyField(ToolOptionValue)
    related_tools = models.ManyToManyField('Tool', blank=True)
    # description = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Status: New')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.tool_type} {[f"{t}, " for t in self.option_values.all()][:-2]}'


class ToolAllocation(models.Model):
    tool = models.OneToOneField(Tool, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    storage_zone = models.ForeignKey(StorageZone, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    work_order_code = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    expect_return = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    start_date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    end_date_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Please format your code in a reable formt.